# Determine more information about PS/2 source with .NET / Windows API?

Tags: .net, winapi

Say I have two peripheral devices, both connected via PS/2 (such as as keyboard and a scanner).  Is there any way to distinguish between the sources programmatically?

I'd like to know whether the input came from the keyboard or the scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`RegisterRawInputDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. For a complete sample application check this article [`Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx).